# Create multiple plots looping several columns

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have a dataset of 20 years with names of species in different columns that I want to plot against the 'season' column. This is what I got but it is not working and only plot the last species (column 18). Can anyone help?

```
for(col_name in names(krill_data2[, 4:18])){
    p1 <- ggplot(data=krill_data2, aes_string(x="Season", y=col_name, fill="Season")) +
     scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall")) +
     scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall")) +
     geom_col(show.legend = TRUE) +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5, hjust=1)) +
     facet_wrap(~Year, nrow=3)
    print(p1)
}
```

Comment: Two options: pivot your data into long format and use  `group_by` (and possibly `group_walk`, depending on the complexity of your plot) or learn about non-standard evaluation in the tidyverse. There are many examples of both approaches on SO. In either case, providing a minimal reproducible example will increase your chances of getting a concrete solution.

Comment: You may also be a victim of lazy evaluation.wrap your `print` in `force()` or switch to a member of the ‘apply` family. A good rule of thumb when writing R code is “if I’m thinking of using a `for` loop, there’s usually a better way to do it”.

Comment: @Limey, Thanks for your interesting comments. Out of curiosity, do you have a link providing a related discussion about `force(print(x))`?

Comment: @Friede: the link to lazy evaluation provided in my suggested dupe.